# Suppress twirl template deprecation method warnings

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5, scalac, twirl

After migration from play `2.4` to `2.5`, we faced with deprecation warnings inside twirl templates:
`...web/templates/main.scala.html:159: method get in object Messages is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
[warn] <a href="@routes.Authentication.login()">@Messages.get("login") </a>
[warn] 1501 warnings found`

`-deprecation` flag inside `scalaOptions` works fine for classes, but looks like it doesn't affect `*.scala.html` files.

Twirl wiki says about `withtwirlRecompilationLogger` `TaskKey` (`twirlRecompilationLogger = TaskKey[(File, File) => Unit]`), but `play 2.5` doesn't contain it (`play.twirl.sbt.TwirlKeys`).

Any ideas how to suppress `deprecation` warnings inside templates?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we want to suppress `deprecation` warnings, we should modify flag with `false` in next way `-deprecation:false`, eg:

`scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation:false")`

Google group discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/play-framework/g7j-8J-f58o).